# IUPAC naming of a haloalkane

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

The IUPAC name of $\ce{(CH3)3C-CH2-CHI-CH3}$ should be **4-iodo-2,2-dimethylpentane** as we consider iodine as a substituent, and we should start numbering from that carbon which is closest to the carbon with maximum number of substituents.

However, [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/2-Iodo-4_4-dimethylpentane) and [Mol-Instincts](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.molinstincts.com/formula/amp/2-Iodo-4-4-dimethylpentane-cfml-CT1097207887.amp.html) state the IUPAC name of this compound as **2-iodo-4,4-dimethylpentane**.

Why not start numbering from the left as there are two methyl group as substituents on the second carbon, and then count iodo on the fourth carbon as it has only one substituent in the form of iodine?

Comment: Neither PubChem nor Mol-Instincts is an authoritative source for chemical nomenclature. PubChem is at least honest with you and informs that the name is auto-generated ("*Computed by LexiChem 2.6.6*") and suggest the correct alternative in the synonyms list, 4-iodo-2,2-dimethylpentane (which you rightfully suggest as well). To answer the question adequately, one must look up for the applicable rules in the [IUPAC Blue Book](https://iupac.org/what-we-do/books/bluebook/).

Comment: @andselisk It's hard to believe that "2-iodo-4,4-dimethylpentane" is really auto-generated. Such a simple case (only an alkane without any substituents would be more simple) should be correct with any automatic algorithm.

Comment: @Loong True. Maybe their algorithm also relies on how frequent a certain name is being used. For some reason there are plenty of patents and publications (https://patents.google.com/?q=SMILES=CC(I)CC(C)(C)C&scholar) going for 2-iodo-4,4-dimethylpentane.